# Loading ajax call response data in DataTable 1.10

Tags: jquery, datatable, datatables

I am implementing search feature where I have two sections on the page. First part is a form to search and second search result table which is hidden at first. So I am trying to load data from the search result in table and show it. So my question are:

1. Where to put DataTable initilization code? Document ready or AJAX success?
2. How to send response from controller to DataTable?

Code Snippet

```
function onSearchClick() {
  $.ajax({
    type: ...
    url: ...
    success: function(response) {
      console.log(response); //Need to send this response to DataTable
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use

```
rows.add()
```

which add multiple rows to the table. Only parameter is a data which DataTable can use to render the rows.

Answer (score 0):

You don't say which version of Datatables you're using, but for 1.9...

Put your datatable initialisation code in `$(document).ready` using `iDeferLoading` to prevent the table populating when the page loads:

```
var oTable = $('#your-table').dataTable({
        'bServerSide': true,
        'sAjaxSource': 'your-url-that-returns-json',
        //  Pass custom param to server
        "fnServerParams": function (aoData) {
            aoData.push({ "name": "my-filter", "value": $('my-selector').val() });
        },
        'bProcessing': true,
        'iDeferLoading': 1,
        'aoColumns': [
         ...
        ]
    });
```

Your click event just needs to call `fnDraw()` to populate the datatable:

```
function onSearchClick() {
    oTable.fnDraw();
}
```

Passing the search parameters to the server-side code involves using `fnServerParams`. Your server side code will have to get these values from the request and use them in the query before returning the filtered data:

```
var searchParam = Request.QueryString["my-filter"]
```

Comment: Sorry its DataTable 1.10